# What is aws-vault actually used for?

Tags: amazon-web-services, credentials

So it says on the github documentation [here](https://github.com/99designs/aws-vault) that

> AWS Vault is a tool to securely store and access AWS credentials in a
>   development environment.
>
> AWS Vault stores IAM credentials in your operating system's secure
>   keystore and then generates temporary credentials from those to expose
>   to your shell and applications. It's designed to be complementary to
>   the AWS CLI tools, and is aware of your

But what does this actually mean? As a developer does this mean to create a kind of lock to prevent anyone from using my code without the aws-vault profile? When should I use this technology? I want to know a bit more about it before I use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually doesn't have anything related to development.

While working with Amazon managed services we can take advantage of IAM roles but that doesn't work when you're doing it from our local environment or from some other Cloud VM like **accessing a S3 bucket**. It comes handy when you're doing a lot of work with AWS CLI or even writing terraform for your environment. It is just for a precaution so we don't expose or IAM credentials to external world **(you will receive an abuse notification from Amazon whenever your keys are compromised)**. There are many other ways to make sure your keys don't get compromised like before pushing your code to a version control use git-secrets to make sure you don't push any sensitive information.